# Ajax code is not running on my visual studio 2015 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I faced an issue when I try to run a code that includes ajax
My friend did that code and it is functioning correctly on her computer, but when I copy the code and run it on my PC it shows me this error !
My platform is `Windows 7`. The environment is `Visual Studio 2015`. The language is `Asp.net` with `C#`

Any help :)
[image: this is the error]

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing `Register Assembly`. Add to top of your page this line

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajx" %>
```

Alo, check if you have `AjaxControlToolkit` under your project's references.

EDIT: As @devio suggested, controls can be also be registered in your web application's `web.config`. Take a look at example [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config).

Comment: controls can also be registered in web.config